# Excel - Formula to Sum of individual sizes with its kitted qty

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to sum up a "Kit" qty with the individual sizes which comprise of that kit. Think of it like Russian dolls, there are small , medium and large sizes individually.. and then there is also " quantity of "kits" of all 3 of them.

So I want to write a formula to see the total number of individual sizes of each size when including the kits.

Please see the example:

[image]

Thank you in advance as I have been racking my brains on this and cant figure it out.. but I know there is a way

Comment: What triggers the number to be the "start of the kit"? IE in your example, the ones that are centered?

Comment: the last 2 characters " K3 "  denotes a kit, which is the "size code"
 
the first 5 charactes = Style number
the middle 3 = Colour Code
the last 2  = Size code

all joined together comprise the SKU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have set up an example sheet similar to yours to which columns A and B are my input that match your example:

[image]

The relevant columns really are only your "Size Code" one and "Qty". The two columns in yellow are "helper columns" to help show you how to accomplish this and column E is your desired output. Of course you can combine equations but I am leaving it separate in the helper columns to better explain to you.

So column C in my case will be used to find any "K3" row and to simply list them in order (start with 1 then 2, so forth):

[image]

Once you have this then I created a column that shows what the last "K3" bin had for qty:

[image]

Now once you have column D established, the rest is just a condition. If the C column has something (not blank) then do not include column D in the sum, and if it does not have something, then do include it.

[image]